# RxJava Flowable.create(), how to respect subscribeOn() thread

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

Im wrapping custom library (`dataClient`) callback api to RxJava Flowable. The `dataClient` uses its own threading, so it's callback is called on its own thread.

In my Rx chain, I try to specify computation scheduler using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())`. Still, when I print thread name on my Rx chain, im getting my `dataClient` thread.

What I should do, to make my Flowable to use thread specified in `.subscribeOn()`?

```
Flowable.create({ emitter ->
    dataClient.setCallback(object : Callback {
        override fun message(message: DataModel) {
            emitter.onNext(vehicle)
        }

        override fun done() {
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    })
    emitter.setCancellable {
        dataClient.setCallback(null)
    }
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnNext { Log.e("DATA", Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { data -> Log.d("DATA", "Got data" + data.id)) }
```

Comment: To move the `onNext` signals to another thread use `observeOn`. `subscribeOn` is for moving subscription side-effects to another thread and has mostly no effect on sources that have their own emission thread.

Comment: Yeah, with `observeOn` I can move to another thread, but in this case is there any use for `subscribeOn `?

Comment: Unless `setCallback` has special threading needs, such as requiring it to be called from the UI or some worker thread, then no.

Answer (score 1):

The `subscribeOn` scheduler ensures that the subscription is done on the relating thread. Subscription happens exactly ones and it's handled differently than the `observeOn` scheduler, which schedules the emission of the element on the new thread.

```
Flowable.create({ emitter ->
    // this runs with the computation scheduler
    dataClient.setCallback(object : Callback {
        override fun message(message: DataModel) {
            // this runs on the thread it's called from
            emitter.onNext(vehicle)
        }

        override fun done() {
            // this runs on the thread it's called from
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    })
    emitter.setCancellable {
        dataClient.setCallback(null)
    }
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnNext {
        // this runs on the thread of the onNext call
        Log.e("DATA", Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        // this runs on the main thread
        data -> Log.d("DATA", "Got data" + data.id))
    }
```

Since your subscription code is not blocking and doesn't maintain the thread for emission, setting up `subscribeOn` is not necessary and could be omitted. It mostly only has effect with synchronous sources.

Comment: Typically when I get Rx api, I set `subscribeOn` based on my needs. With this example `subscribeOn` has no affect and I fear that when another developer uses my api, they also set `subscribeOn` based on their need. This leads to issue that Rx chain is running on another thread they are expecting. How should I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `subscribeOn` for this need. If it was called before on the chain already, it doesn't have any effect anyhow. Only the first call will be considered.